# Embedding YouTube videos on Joomla site

Tags: video, joomla, youtube

We have hired a web design company to create a Joomla site for us. One of the web pages needs to show some videos that are hosted on YouTube. The web designers say that there is a limitation with the Joomla - YouTube API that limits the number of videos to be shown to a maximum of 5. Is this true? Where can I find this documented and explained? Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never heard of this. It's unlikely youtube has this limit, because I remember seeing web pages with more than 5 embedded youtube videos. Joomla doesn't natively support embedded youtoube videos(as of January 2011, didn't check since then) but there are [plenty of free 3rd part plugins](http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=embed%20youtube) out there for this purpose. Maybe they are using a free version of 3rd party plugin and it has 5 video per page limit?

As long as Youtube supports this, it should be possible. It's also very easy to code such plugin. I think you should ask an explanation from them.

Answer (score 1):

With this plugin I embedded 13 youtube videos to a page ... I can give you the working link if needed ... so it's not true !

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/multimedia/multimedia-players/video-players-a-gallery/812?qh=YToyOntpOjA7czo5OiJhbGx2aWRlb3MiO2k6MTtzOjg6ImFsbHZpZGVvIjt9